# How can I cut scenes out of a DVD?

Tags: dvd, ripping, authoring

I want to be able to rip a commercial DVD, then edit some scenes, and then burn it back onto DVD to put back in my collection.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A multi-stage process probably.

First, get the video with [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/details.php). Output to MP4. Use [avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) to edit. Then create a DVD with something like [dvdflick](http://www.dvdflick.net/).

Comment: yick.  it'll work, yes, but you lose quality in the transcode -- twice, once to MP4, then again back to MPEG2.  AviDemux may be able to handle editing the original video directly, but i haven't tried it.  process should be: 1) rip/decode (straight to hard drive); 2) open in AviDemux & edit (maybe save-as to new copy); 3) reauthor (if necessary); 4) burn DVD-video-on-hard-drive using ImgBurn or Nero or some other burner application.  this may require reencoding the video, but only one, and there's a good chance you won't lose quality on it.

Comment: IF you put this as an answer ~quack, I'm happy for the acceptance to go to you!

Comment: I am not super concerned about quality.  But I will take a look at quacks alternative if i think the quality is too poor.

Comment: @quack Using the way's described will result in something of "imprecise" edits, won't it, since avidemux has to split on i-frames?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with the help of "[WinDvd-creator](http://download.cnet.com/WinDVD-Creator-Platinum/3000-7970_4-10217654.html)".